# Interface the chatbot with our wordPress?

Tags: wordpress

How to interface the chatbot in WordPress and what plugin should be used for this one to implement in our website?

Answer (score 2):

[Kommunicate](https://www.kommunicate.io/) provides a Livechat Bot plugin to integrate with WordPress websites. Here the [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/kommunicate-live-chat/) to the WP chatbot plugin.

This chatbot plugin enables you to talk to your website visitors easily through live chat and chat-bots. It also provides a set of Actionable Messages.

You can create your own custom bots using our chatbot builder – [Kompose](https://www.kommunicate.io/product/kompose-bot-builder?v2) or add any [Dialogflow](https://docs.kommunicate.io/docs/bot-dialogflow-integration), Amazon Lex, or custom-made chat-bots to your website using the live chat plugin.